# Are there functions to retrieve the histogram counts of a Series in pandas?

Tags: pandas, histogram, series

There is a method to **plot** Series histograms, but is there a function to retrieve the histogram counts to do further calculations on top of it?

I keep using numpy's functions to do this and converting the result to a DataFrame or Series when I need this. It would be nice to stay with pandas objects the whole time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your Series was discrete you could use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3])

In [12]: s.value_counts()
Out[12]:
2    3
1    3
3    1
dtype: int64
```

*You can see that [`s.hist()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html) is essentially equivalent to `s.value_counts().plot()`.*

If it was of floats an awful hacky solution could be to use groupby:

```
s.groupby(lambda i: np.floor(2*s[i]) / 2).count()
```

Comment: I have floating point numbers. :( Most of those counts will be 1. This may still useful for cumulative distributions though, thanks. Can I resample somehow like I can do with TimeSeries?

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini ah, I see!

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini well, I have a hacky way, it seems likely there is a better way (pandas-foo isn't with me today).

Comment: Note that `value_counts` now has a `bins` argument to handle floats nicely.

Answer (score 14):

Since `hist` and `value_counts` don't use the Series' index, you may as well treat the Series like an ordinary array and use `np.histogram` directly. Then build a Series from the result.

```
In [4]: s = Series(randn(100))

In [5]: counts, bins = np.histogram(s)

In [6]: Series(counts, index=bins[:-1])
Out[6]: 
-2.968575     1
-2.355032     4
-1.741488     5
-1.127944    26
-0.514401    23
 0.099143    23
 0.712686    12
 1.326230     5
 1.939773     0
 2.553317     1
dtype: int32
```

This is a really convenient way to organize the result of a histogram for subsequent computation.

To index by the *center* of each bin instead of the left edge, you could use `bins[:-1] + np.diff(bins)/2`.

Comment: this is just so much nicer :)

Comment: This is close to what I usually do. I was just curious if there was a built in pandas function for that.

Answer (score 7):

If you know the number of bins you want, you can use pandas' [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.cut.html) function, which is now accessible via [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Using the same random example:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
s.value_counts(bins=5)

Out[55]: 
(-0.512, 0.311]     40
(0.311, 1.133]      25
(-1.335, -0.512]    14
(1.133, 1.956]      13
(-2.161, -1.335]     8
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33895378/3107708) answer from a related question you can get the bin edges and histogram counts as follows:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
ax = s.hist()

for rect in dd.patches:
    ((x0, y0), (x1, y1)) = rect.get_bbox().get_points()
    print(((x0, y0), (x1, y1)))
```