# pandas - add a column with value based on exisitng one (bins, qcut)

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I am slowly moving from **R** to **python** + **pandas**, and I am facing a problem I cannot solve...

I need to discretize values from one column, by assigning them to bins and adding a column with those bin names to original `DataFrame`. I am trying to use `pandas.qcut`, but the resulting `Categorical` object seems to be not playing well with `DataFrame`.

An example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), columns=['a'])
df1['binned_a'] = pd.qcut(df1['a'],4)
```

Now when trying to invoke `describe` on `df1` I cannot see the new column:

```
>>> df1.describe()
               a
count  10.000000
mean    0.594072
std     1.109981
min    -0.807307
25%    -0.304550
50%     0.545839
75%     1.189487
max     2.851922
```

However, it apparently is there:

```
>>> df1
          a          binned_a
0  0.190015   (-0.305, 0.546]
1  0.140227   (-0.305, 0.546]
2  1.380000    (1.189, 2.852]
3 -0.522530  [-0.807, -0.305]
4 -0.452810  [-0.807, -0.305]
5  2.851922    (1.189, 2.852]
6 -0.807307  [-0.807, -0.305]
7  0.901663    (0.546, 1.189]
8  1.010334    (0.546, 1.189]
9  1.249205    (1.189, 2.852]
```

What am I doing wrong? My desired result is to get a column with 4 unique string values describing the bins (like factors in R).

---

**EDIT:**

As correctly spotted by Dan, the `summary()` method won't show column with text-only data and so the mysterious problem is solved :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never been an R user, but if I understand you, you want to group the data into bins and describe each bin.

```
In [9]: df.groupby('binned_a').describe().unstack()
Out[9]:               a                                                   \
                  count      mean       std       min       25%       50%   
binned_a                                                                    
(-0.113, 0.109]       2  0.025114  0.010264  0.017856  0.021485  0.025114   
(-0.337, -0.113]      2 -0.282838  0.056445 -0.322751 -0.302794 -0.282838   
(0.109, 0.563]        3  0.354481  0.214402  0.134978  0.250027  0.365076   
[-1.842, -0.337]      3 -1.003969  0.765167 -1.841622 -1.335073 -0.828523   


                   75%       max  
binned_a                              
(-0.113, 0.109]   0.028742  0.032371  
(-0.337, -0.113] -0.262882 -0.242925  
(0.109, 0.563]    0.464233  0.563390  
[-1.842, -0.337] -0.585142 -0.341762
```

To avoid Categoricals altogether, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150734/1221924

Comment: Not exactly, in fact I am just wondering why the new `binned_a` column is not showing in the `describe` result...

However, I have tried doing `df1['binned_a'] = pd.Series(pd.qcut(df1['a'],4))` and still no result...

Comment: The "bins" in ``binned_a`` are strings, so ``describe()`` is ignoring them. Would exactly about the bins would you like to describe?

Comment: Ahhh, indeed... I thought that when a column is not showing in `describe()` then something is wrong (in R text columns are also shown in summry)... 
So it seems to be clear now, thanks a lot!