# Get values from matplotlib AxesSubplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to get values from `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot` which is returned from [pandas.Series.hist](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html) method.
Is there any method to do so? I couldn't find the attribute in the list.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

serie = pd.Series([0.0,950.0,-70.0,812.0,0.0,-90.0,0.0,0.0,-90.0,0.0,-64.0,208.0,0.0,-90.0,0.0,-80.0,0.0,0.0,-80.0,-48.0,840.0,-100.0,190.0,130.0,-100.0,-100.0,0.0,-50.0,0.0,-100.0,-100.0,0.0,-90.0,0.0,-90.0,-90.0,63.0,-90.0,0.0,0.0,-90.0,-80.0,0.0,])
hist = serie.hist()
# I want to get values of hist variable.
```

I know I can get histogram values with `np.histogram`, but I want to use pandas hist method.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible: the Pandas [plotting.py source](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py) seems to throw away the binned data, bin edges and patch objects that matplotlib returns to it. Why not plot directly with `plt.hist`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As `xnx` pointed out in comments, this isn't as easily accessible as if you used `plt.hist`. However, if you really want to use the pandas `hist` function, you *can* get this information, from the `patches` that are added to the `hist` `AxesSubplot` when you call `serie.hist`.

Here's a function to loop through the patches, and return the bin edges and histogram counts:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

serie = pd.Series([0.0,950.0,-70.0,812.0,0.0,-90.0,0.0,0.0,-90.0,0.0,-64.0,208.0,0.0,-90.0,0.0,-80.0,0.0,0.0,-80.0,-48.0,840.0,-100.0,190.0,130.0,-100.0,-100.0,0.0,-50.0,0.0,-100.0,-100.0,0.0,-90.0,0.0,-90.0,-90.0,63.0,-90.0,0.0,0.0,-90.0,-80.0,0.0,])
hist = serie.hist()

def get_hist(ax):
    n,bins = [],[]
    for rect in ax.patches:
        ((x0, y0), (x1, y1)) = rect.get_bbox().get_points()
        n.append(y1-y0)
        bins.append(x0) # left edge of each bin
    bins.append(x1) # also get right edge of last bin

    return n,bins

n, bins = get_hist(hist)

print n
print bins

plt.show()
```

Here's the output of `n` and `bins`:

```
[36.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0]                          # n
[-100.0, 5.0, 110.0, 215.0, 320.0, 425.0, 530.0, 635.0, 740.0, 845.0, 950.0] # bins
```

And here's the histogram plot to check:

[image]