# How to get bin ranges for histograms created through pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am in need of retrieving the default bins that were used for a `histogram` generated by `dataframe.hist` rather than `plt.hist`.

I found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442224/getting-information-for-bins-in-matplotlib-histogram-function) on `plt.hist`, but I also found out that `dataframe.hist` returns a subplot while `plt.hist` returns a tuple. I'm therefore unsure as to how I can retrieve the bin ranges for the `dataframe.hist`.

What can I try next?

Comment: @MedAli The actual bins. This means having access to the max and mins of each bin.

Comment: This question is actually answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888973/get-values-from-matplotlib-axessubplot So perhaps it should get closed as duplicate