# Return max bin value in panda histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am VERY new to Python, and I am looking for a solution to my problem.  In particular, I need to return the max value of the bins in my historgram...and am at a loss on how to proceed.  My dataframe is a pandas dataframe as:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(filename)

bin_array = np.linspace(start=0., stop=10., num=150)
df.series.hist(bins=bin_array)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Special Thanks go to David G ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/5851928/davidg) for properly formatting my post!

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148787/are-there-functions-to-retrieve-the-histogram-counts-of-a-series-in-pandas. Highly likely to be cleaner to use numpy function directly to produce the histogram info, then plot if needed.

Comment: Yep, almost definitely better to use `numpy`

Comment: David G, THANKS!  I missed that post in my search - and it was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to just use numpy's `histogram` function directly.  It is what pandas is calling behind the scenes to generate the plot.

```
bin_array = np.linspace(start=0., stop=10., num=150)
counts, bins = np.histogram(df.series, bins=bin_array)
```